# using Math.max for a BankAccount class

Tags: java

I have a homework problem in which I have to deduct a fee for each transaction in a bank account which goes over the allotted number of free transactions. My problem is that my `Math.max` is not working for the `deductMonthlyCharge` class, instead of applying the charge only when the transaction go over the allotted amount, the program is charging the fee for EVERY transaction. I have no idea how to fix this. Also, I am supposed to reset the transaction count after every month. I have no idea how to do this. If someone could nudge me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Here is my BankAccount code:

```
public class BankAccount
{  
   private double balance;
   private double fee;
   private double freeTransactions;
   private double transactionCount;

   public BankAccount()
   {   
      balance = 0;
      fee = 5;
      freeTransactions = 5;
      transactionCount = 0;
   }

   public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
   {   
      balance = initialBalance;
      transactionCount = 0;
   }

   public void deposit(double amount)
   {  
      double newBalance = balance + amount;
      balance = newBalance;
      transactionCount++;
   }

   public void withdraw(double amount)
   {   
      double newBalance = balance - amount;
      balance = newBalance;
      transactionCount++;
   }

   public double getBalance()
   {   
      return balance;
   }    

   public void setTransFee(double amount)
   { 
       balance = amount+(balance-fee);
       balance = balance;
   }

   public void setNumFreeTrans(double amount) 
   {
       amount = freeTransactions;
   }

   public double deductMonthlyCharge()
   {
       double transCount = Math.max(transactionCount, freeTransactions);
       double fee = 2.00 * (transCount - freeTransactions);
       return fee;
   }
}
```

Here's my BankAccountTester code:

```
public class BankAccountTester
    {
        private BankAccount rockdown;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BankAccount rockdown = new BankAccount(1000.0);
            rockdown.deposit(1000);
            rockdown.withdraw(500);
            rockdown.withdraw(400);
            rockdown.deposit(200);
            System.out.println(rockdown.getBalance()- rockdown.deductMonthlyCharge());

            rockdown.deposit(1000);
            rockdown.withdraw(500);
            rockdown.withdraw(400);
            rockdown.deposit(200);
            rockdown.deposit(500);
            System.out.println(rockdown.getBalance()- rockdown.deductMonthlyCharge());

            rockdown.deposit(1000);
            rockdown.withdraw(500);
            rockdown.withdraw(400);
            rockdown.deposit(200);
            rockdown.deposit(500);
            rockdown.withdraw(1000);
            System.out.println(rockdown.getBalance()- rockdown.deductMonthlyCharge());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this is homework, but financial transactions should **never** be done with a floating point type, like double or float.

Answer (score 3):

You never set the `freeTransactions` in your *non-default* constructor so it defaults to `0`:

```
public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
```

You could call your default constructor from the overloaded one like so:

```
public BankAccount(double initialBalance) {   
   super();
   balance = initialBalance;
}
```

so that the statement `freeTransactions = 5;` is called.

Comment: I see `freeTransactions = 5` in the constructor.  What are you referring to?

Comment: That is in the default constructor but not the one that is being called

Comment: Ah. this is true.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a couple of lines from one of your constructors.

```
   public BankAccount()
   {   
      balance = 0;
      fee = 5;
      freeTransactions = 5;
      transactionCount = 0;
   }

   public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
   {   
      balance = initialBalance;
      fee = 5;
      freeTransactions = 5;
      transactionCount = 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max(a,b)` is correct and returns the greater value.
You may want to change your method to only calc a fee, if there is a fee to calc, thus there are not free transactions left.

Btw. `freeTransactions` and `fee` should be set by declaration or in construction.

```
public double deductMonthlyCharge()
   {
       double transCount = Math.max(transactionCount, freeTransactions) - freeTransactions;
       double fee = 0;
       if (transCount > 0) fee = 2.00 * transCount;
       return fee;
   }
```

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way instead of trying to use Math.

```
if (transactionCount <= freeTransactions)
   return 0;
return 2 * (transactionCount - freeTransactions);
```

Comment: You missed that `freeTransactions` may be initialized to zero, which isn't wanted.

Comment: @tuergeist It could be that free transactions are only available to new accounts. :|  I don't know why the counts are double and not `int` or `long` and a bunch of other things I would do differently. ;)